# linq equivalent sql query "not in (select query)"

Tags: .net, sql, linq

my sql code is as follows:

```
select UserId,UserName 
from aspnet_Users 
where UserId not in (select UsersId from tbluser  where active='true')
```

what is the equivalent linq expression?

Comment: !.Contains() or .Except() are the two ways I'm aware of

Answer (score 11, accepted):

my first try using `LiNQ` in `C#`

```
var result = from y in aspnet_Users
            where !(
                        from x in tblUser
                        where  x.active == "true"
                        select x.UsersID
                    ).Contains(y.UserId)
            select y;                
            -- OR // select new { y.UserId, y.UserName};
```

SOURCE

- [The NOT IN clause in LINQ to SQL](http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: I think it should be `x.active`

Comment: The link is dead, I find the last version of that on webarchive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121005152736/http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query =
    from c in aspnet_Users 
    where !(from o in tbluser where o.active=="true" 
            select o.UserId)
           .Contains(c.UserId)
    select c;
```

Comment: How does your **copy** differs from @JW answer?

Comment: I didn't observe @jw answer, after posting my answer then i came to know that both are same.

Comment: `where !aspnet_Users.Any(p => p.active== "true")` don't looks like same. Am I missing something here?